# Save data into mysql from hive hadoop through sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have my data store into hive table. 
i want to transfer hive tables selected data to mysql table using sqoop.

Please guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the sqoop guide [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sqoop export, here is the example

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_rpt_db" \
   --username retail_dba \
   --password cloudera \
   --table departments \
   --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/retail_ods.db/departments \
   --input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
   --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
   --num-mappers 2
```

sqoop export to export data to mysql from Hadoop.

1. --connect JDBC url
2. --username mysql username
3. --password password for mysql user
4. --table mysql table name
5. --export-dir valid hadoop directory
6. --input-fields-terminated-by column delimiter in Hadoop
7. --input-lines-terminated-by row delimiter in Hadoop
8. --num-mappers number of mappers to process the data