# How to import MySQL data to Hadoop file system?

Tags: mysql, hadoop2, sqoop2, sqoop

In my system I have database in Mysql. I want to import that to hadoop file system. I found something about Sqoop, but i'm not getting command to do that.

Comment: Here is the answer on other thread.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631957/save-data-into-mysql-from-hive-hadoop-through-sqoop/34019965#34019965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql-server-name/db_name --username user --password password --table table_name --target-dir target_directory_name -m1

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql jdbc/java connector and run sqoop command.

```
sudo yum install mysql-connector-java
ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar /var/lib/sqoop/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

You can run sqoop command from
[Save data into mysql from hive hadoop through sqoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631957/save-data-into-mysql-from-hive-hadoop-through-sqoop/34019965#34019965)

Answer (score 0):

1) Install & configure MySQL first. Create database in MySQL

2) `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename --username $USER_NAME --password $PASSWORD$ --table tablename --m 1` command will import data.

e.g.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDb --username root --password hadoop123 --table student --m 1

In above command, values of various parameters `database:‘testDb’` , `username: ‘root’`, `password: ‘hadoop123’`, and `table student`.

Have a look at this [article 1](https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/sqoopimporting-data-from-mysql-into-hdfs/) and [article 2](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html) for better understanding in step-by-step manner

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this,

1. The old way is to use [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/)
2. Another way is to use Shell Script,

   a. Connect with MySQL(`mysql -h<host> -u<username> -p<password>`)

   b. Open connectivity with HDFS(`hadoop fs`)

   c. Run `SELECT` on table and do `put hdfs`
3. Recommended way is to use [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/)

   a. Use ExecuteSQL, PutHDFS processors